# store autocomplete source (Mvc 4)

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, wcf, autocomplete

I´m calling a function to get the source of the autocomplete. My jquery function call a controller, the controller call a method and the method call a wcf service. My wcf serice return a list of addresses.
I want to  know if there is a way to store the list of addresses in the first call (while the user remains on the view) to prevent call the service every time the user use the autocomplete textbox. I tried to do it with a static list but the list of address on the db can change and need to be reloaded (at least in the first call when the users go to the view).
Here is my code.

Autocomplete:

```
    $(function () {
        var availableTags = {                
            source: '/Address/GetAddresses/',
            minLength: 4,
            }            
        $("input.Places").live("keydown.autocomplete", function () {
            $(this).autocomplete(availableTags);
        });
    });
```

Controller:

```
    public ActionResult GetAddresses(string term)
    {
        var filteredItems = City.GetFilteredAddresses(term);
        return Json(filteredItems, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Method:

```
    public static IEnumerable<string> GetFilteredAddresses(string term)
    {
        var items = AddressesService(); This method call a wcf service and return the list of addresses
        var filteredItems = items.Where(
            item => item.IndexOf(term, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0
            );
        return filteredItems;
    }
```

Comment: Why not make a call to that method on document.ready and store that list in a global variable say list and then in the source of auto complete, say source:list?

Comment: Are you trying to reduce server processing or bandwidth? (or both?)

Comment: @Sarcastic i tried but for some reason the textbox didnt show the options

Comment: @HiTechMagic both, because the list of addreeses could be long

Comment: Can you show the code for that?

Comment: @Sarcastic sure, let me do it again

Comment: As you are concerned about both, I suggest a modified rest service where you pass in a last-queried date. This allows for change-checks on the server-side and return of only new records to the client. You can then cache data on both sides.

Comment: @Sarcastic i did the global variable inside the document.ready and the textbox show the options but unfiltered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did what Sarcastic said, i create a new function to get the list of address and store it in a global variable. 
Here is the code:

```
    var list;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Address/GetListAddresses/',
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                list = data;
            }
        });
    });
```

Autocomplete

```
$(function () {
        var availableTags = {
            source: function (request, response) {
                response($.ui.autocomplete.filter(list, request.term));
            },
            minLength: 4,
        }                        
        $("input.Places").live("keydown.autocomplete", function () {
            $(this).autocomplete(availableTags);
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

The list is not getting populated because the GetAddresses method in your controller is expecting one string argument, but you are not passing any.

```
public ActionResult GetAddresses(string term)
```

The workaround for that maybe that you get a list of all the addresses on DOM ready irrespective of the character entered by user. You will have to modify your controller and WCF code for that. Once you get list of all the addressed, you can simply say

```
source:list
```

and it will save you the ajax calls. This will be viable if list of addresses in not very large which I am assuming to be correct.

No need to pass any arguments to controller and simply remove this filter option and let it pass the whole list to the ajax call.

```
var filteredItems = items.Where(
        item => item.IndexOf(term, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a callback and simply cache the results locally.

From the following link: [jQuery UI Autocomplete and Caching Query Results](http://developwithstyle.com/articles/2010/05/14/jquery-ui-autocomplete-is-it-any-good/)

```
var cache = {};
$("#birds").autocomplete({
  source: function(request, response) {
      if (cache.term == request.term && cache.content) {
          response(cache.content);
          return;
      }
      if (new RegExp(cache.term).test(request.term) && cache.content && cache.content.length
```

Comment: Thanks but this only cache the results for a inputted word, if the user, type a new word, the function call again the web service, i want to store the whole list

Comment: You control the source of jQuery autocomplete data. Cache the list from a call to whatever method you get your _complete_ word list from. After that you  control the source and can simply regex your local word list cache as shown in the sample above